# export python script output variable to different columns in csv in python

Tags: python, csv, export

My python script is giving output to 4 variables like

```
output = (x, y, attributes1, attributes2)
print(output)
```

where output is like

```
('Location', 'People', ['USA', 'UK', 'Brazil'], ['Mohit', 'Aryan'])
('People', 'College', ['Mohit', 'Aryan', 'Tom'], ['Havard', 'Oxford'])....
and thousands of output like this

where 'Location' is x variable
  'People' is y variable
  ['USA', 'UK', 'Brazil'] is attributes1 and 
  ['Mohit', 'Aryan'] is attributes2
```

So how can i export these four variables(x,y,attributes1,attributes2) in a csv file so that different variables comes in different columns.

Output will be like:

```
x                 y            attributes1            attributes2
Location         People     ['USA', 'UK', 'Brazil']    ['Mohit', 'Aryan']
People           College    ['Mohit', 'Aryan', 'Tom']  ['Havard', 'Oxford']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas` as it scale up really well. For example,

```
import pandas as pd
x = 'Loacation'
y = 'People'
attribute1 = ['USA', 'UK', 'Brazil']
attribute2 = ['Mohit', 'Aryan']

df = pd.DataFrame([x, y, attribute1, attribute2],
         index = ('x', 'y', 'attribute1', 'attribute2')).transpose()

with open(r'D:\file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df.to_string())
```

Ouput:

```
           x       y         attribute1      attribute2
0  Loacation  People  [USA, UK, Brazil]  [Mohit, Aryan]
```

or for excel file, replace last tow lines with,

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'D:\text.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
```

Comment: but i want it in a csv file where x,y,attribute1,attribute2 will come in different columns

Comment: use `pandas.ExcelWriter` for excel file. You should understand, `csv` file stands for `comma seperated values` file. People also use `space`, `tab`, `;` as seperator but hen you open it in Microsofet Excel, they appear in one column. If you really want in different columns in microsoft excel then use `pandas.ExcelWriter`.